# How to configure RestTemplate debug logging in log4j2 xml

Tags: json, xml, spring, log4j2, resttemplate

I am using log4j2 with xml configuration. I want to log all the JSON created by `restTemplate`

How can I configure it in log4j2 xml configuration file to log these?

Answer (score 1):

If your RestTemplate uses apache http client, your log4j2.xml configuration could look like this:

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.web.client" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="APP" level="DEBUG"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="APP" level="DEBUG"/>
</Logger>
```

RestTemplate Initialisation:

```
org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000);
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```